# iOS WebView form assistant - Android analogue?

Tags: android, webview

On my iPhone when the virtual keyboard pops up for a form field, there are some navigation buttons showing up at the top of the keyboard, which are: "previous", "next", "done". (And sometimes "autofill").

This is apparently the Mobile Safari "form assistant" and it also appears on the WebView in my application.

Is there anything similar for the Android WebView? Any third-party solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Android supports this natively.

You probably need to implement your own navigation which would probably be easiest as part of your web page.

Comment: I did not have to implement this myself for iOS and I do not want to do it for Android either; or are you saying iOS is better than Android (to which I might probably agree) =)

Comment: You are putting words into my mouth.  There is some nice functionality included out of the box with iOS.  Android is my platform of choice, because I love it's openness.  Both platforms have their pros\cons - I would say they are both good for different things.